# If $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(a)=0=f(b)$, $f'(a)>0$ and $f'(b)>0$ where $a<b$ Show that for some $c$ in $(a,b)$, $f(c)=0$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

> If $f: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable function such that $f(a)=0=f(b)$, $f'(a)>0$ and $f'(b)>0$ where $a<b$ Show that for some $c$ in $(a,b)$, $f(c)=0$.

I have try proving by
Start from $f$ is continuous and increasing at $a$ and $b$ but I don't know how to describe it clearly through $f(c)=0$. can I use the rolle's theorem but does is clear $f'(c)=0$ then $f(c)$ have to be zero.

Could yo help please!

Comment: What does Rolle's theorem say?

Comment: If a real-valued function f is continuous on a proper closed interval [a, b], differentiable on the open interval (a, b), and f(a) = f(b), then there exists at least one c in the open interval (a, b) such that f'(c)=0.

Comment: Look at $\sin$ on $[0,2\pi]$. Its derivative will be zero at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $3\frac{\pi}{2}$, but $\sin$ is not exactly zero there (it's $1$ and $-1$ resp.).

Comment: Figure out how you can use the Mean value theorem to prove that there is a point where the function is positive and there's a point where it is negative. Then argue using continuity.

Comment: @Nekken, yes you are right. And it is not helpful here, as others have commented. The crucial piece of information is the fact that $f$ has a positive derivative at the end-points of the interval.

Answer (score 2):

First off, just because $f'(c)=0$ does not mean $f(c)=0$, and it's probably not. So, don't use Rolle.

Now, consider the set $T=\{t | f(x)\geq 0,\ \forall\ x\in [a,t)\}$. Now, what is $\sup(T)$? If $b=\sup(T)$ then you can show $f'(b)\leq 0$ because (in this case) for ALL $x\in [a,b)$, $f(x)\geq 0$. This is a contradiction, so $\sup(T) \neq b$. Thus $\sup(T)<b$ and exists because $T$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$. By continuity of $f$ you can argue that $f(\sup(T)) = 0$. (I'll leave that to you.) Hence $c=\sup(T)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Because $f'(a) > 0,$ $f$ must be positive somewhere to the right of $a.$ If $f$ were never $0$ in $(a,b),$ then we would have $f>0$ in $(a,b)$ by the IVT. But then

$$\frac{f(b-h)-f(b)}{(b-h)-b}= \frac{f(b-h)}{-h}<0$$ for small positive $h.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(a)=0,f'(a)>0$ imply that $f(x)>0$ in $(a,a+\delta_1]$ for some $\delta_1>0$ and that $f(b)=0,f'(b)>0$ imply that $f(x)<0$ in $[b-\delta_2,b)$ for some $\delta_2>0$. Choose $\delta_1,\delta_2$ small such that $a+\delta_1<b-\delta_2$. Now $f(a+\delta_1)f(b-\delta_2)<0$, by the IMVT, there is $c\in(a+\delta_1,b-\delta_2)\subset(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$.